# add 3 text in ListTile, change background color for each column, and add search in this list

Tags: flutter, listview, dart

How can I add a search in my listview below please
And is it possible to add 3 text in my ListTile if yes how can I do please.
And how can I do to change background colors in my list one time blue and second green etc......
Thank you for your help

```
   body: StreamBuilder<List>(
        stream: _streamController.stream,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData)
            return ListView(
              children: [
                for (Map document in snapshot.data)
                Card(
                  elevation: 10.6,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: new ListTile(
                         title: Text(document['title1'],   textScaleFactor: 1.2, style: TextStyle(color:Colors.white),),
                         subtitle: Text(document['title2'], textScaleFactor: 1.2, style: TextStyle(color:Colors.white),),
                    leading: new IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.headset, color: Colors.white),
                      onPressed: () {
                        //***//
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                   ),
                  ],
                 );
          return Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  CircularProgressIndicator()
                ],
              ),
          );
        },
      ),
```

Comment: I found about color I did
 color: (changeColors()) ? Colors.blue[600] : Colors.blue[800],

changeColors() {
      _color=!_color;
      return _color;
  }

But I dont found about search in my ListView

Answer (score 1):

- For a start on search in your ListView you can check this out: https://blog.usejournal.com/flutter-search-in-listview-1ffa40956685

  Or use a `SearchDelegate` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SearchDelegate-class.html
- ListTiles just take widgets as leading, title, subtitle, and trailing. So you can put whatever you want in there!

```dart
ListTile(
  title: Column(
    children: [
      Text('abc'),
      Text('def'),
      //etc,
    ],
  ),
  subtitle: Column(
    children: [
      Text('123'),
      Text('456'),
      //etc,
    ],
   ),
),
```

- For changing the colour you want to take a look at `Listview.builder`. It uses an `IndexWidgetBuilder` which provides an index that way you can use your index to check if its even or uneven to set the preferred colour.
  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html

Comment: Ello Er1 thank you a lot for your help about search I found a solution with php and mysql